# Can the limit of averages of $f(1),f(2),\dots, f(n)$ be expressed as an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

If $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ exists then, of course,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{2}{n})+\ldots+f(\frac{n}{n})}{n} = \int_0^1 f(x) dx.
$$
I would like to know is there a similar formula for
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(1)+f(2)+\ldots+f(n)}{n} 
$$
under some assumptions on $f$.

Comment: But you have no "If " statement for the second one.

Comment: if f is monotonicly decreasing then, $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty} f(i) < \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$.

Comment: This limit equals $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)$, provided this exists.

Comment: @Crostul is very right. It is called sthg like limit of avrages theorem.

Comment: If the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)$ converges to, say $L$, then the limit of interest is also $L$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Cesaro sommation (but Cesaro cared more about series than functions)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

Comment: It does not! Cesaro os alternative sumation method

Comment: @wroobell It is exactly a Cesaro summation.   Why do you believe - and so emphatically - that it is not?  I would admonish you to refrain from using an exclamation point in the way you did.  It can be interpreted as quite uncivil.

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(x)$
is monotonic increasing,
then
$f(n)
< \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
< f(n+1)
$.

Therefore
$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)
< \int_0^n f(x) dx
< \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)
$
or
$\frac1{n}(f(0)-f(n))
< \int_0^n f(x) dx-\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)
< 0
$.

Therefore,
if $f(x)$
is monotonic increasing
and
$\dfrac{f(n)}{n}
\to 0
$,
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^n f(x) dx-\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)
\to 0
$.

This is a sufficient condition.

Other sufficient conditions
can be similarly derived.

You might see what you can derive if
$f(x)$
is monotonic decreasing.

Have fun.